# Copy Workbook name then Activate workbook with copyed name later with vba

Tags: excel, vba

I Have `WName = ThisWorkbook.Name` and then I want to set `Windows("WName").Activate` at another point in my code but is not working.

I am aware this might not make sense but it does with all of the sutf that is going on

below is a small test sub (I am not using this just trying to get it to work)

Thanks

```
 Sub test()
 'Copy Active Workbook Name
 WName = ThisWorkbook.Name

 'Activate a different Workbook
 Windows("MyWorkbookAAA").Activate

 'Activate Original workbook using WName
 Windows("WName").Activate  'Have also tried Windows(WName).Activate

 range("D2:D25").Select
 Selection.Copy

 Windows("MyWorkbookBBB").Activate
 range("C22").Select
 ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

Avoid using Select/Activate in your code . Refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select)

```
 ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("D2:D25").Copy Workbooks("MyWorkbookBBB").ActiveSheet.Range("C22")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the information and code,I had gotten the code from recording a macro, I have that kind off code in a number of places, I will need to replace it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep similar syntax by keeping a reference to your string value WName.

```
Workbooks(WName).Activate
```

This activates that workbook.

Also can do

```
ThisWorkbook.Activate
```

if it's the workbook running your code.

(there are easier ways to do the specific operation you are ONLY doing one thing like copying, but this explains how to do what you are trying to do)